# How can I remove the commented text in html using htmlagilitypack

Tags: html-agility-pack

Is it possible to remove the commented text in html using **htmlagilitypack** library? Currently I'm doing some migrating work from ASP to ASP.NET MVC and there it's used **Regex** for those things and just want to know can I achieve that using **htmlagilitypack** before starting to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find all the nodes of type `HtmlCommentNode` (which represents an HTML comment) and remove it from the document. But note, AgilityPack treats e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>` as a comment node too. So nodes like this should be skipped for deletion:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var comments = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<HtmlCommentNode>()
    .Where(c=> 
        !c.Comment.StartsWith("<!DOCTYPE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    ).ToList();

foreach (var comment in comments)
    comment.Remove();

var result = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```